# assembly programming

Tags: assembly, addition, subtraction

```
R0 = 1500 
R1 = 4500
R2 = 1000
```

Show the effective address of memory and the registers’ contents in each of the following instructions :

```
ADD (R0)+, R2

SUBTRACT - (R1), R2
```

Possible Answer :

Addition :

```
R2 = M[1500] + 1000 , R0 = 1501
```

Subtraction :

```
R2 = M[4500] – 1000 , R1 = 4501
```

What is the right answer, please help

Comment: Probably homework.   You're not likely to get any help, some things you have do by yourself.  Any good assembly language book will teach you the answers.

Answer (score 0):

What machine is it? Some pdp/vax?
This instruction:

```
ADD (R0)+, R2
```

shouldn't it add size of operand? 16 bits in your case, not 8 I guess?

Sub part is not right, since there is definitely auto-decrement used. And if I recall correctly, it is done before loading an operand.